# What is the proper way to store 'metadata' in relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, rdbms

I have a table called `assets`, where an asset can belong to a user,team, or division, and possibly multiple of each. My issue is that the assets are highly variable, and can have properties associated with them that are different for each one.

ex. These could be assets:

```
1.)
type:workbench
cost:200
vendor:Acme Co.
color:black
2.)
type:microscope
serial_no:BH-00102
purchase_date:1337800923
cost:2040
```

and this could go on for hundreds to thousands of different types of assets.

How would I store this type of data in a normalized way that would be easy to query, without altering my tables every time a new asset type is added? Some of the fields are the present across all assets too, such as cost.

So far I figure that I should have:

```
assets
id,cost,purchase_date,asset_type_id

asset_types
id,name

division_assets
division_id,asset_id

user_assets
user_id,asset_id
```

but i do not know where to put the data that varies

Comment: Is one property can be related to number of assets ?

Comment: some properties are for all assets, but all other ones that aren't will be specific to individual asset types.

Comment: Are you going to search on those variable properties? Also, read up on [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: If you were using Postgres you can use the hstore module which does this very efficiently.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for sharing, didn't know about that! https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres: in 2022 it's probably better to use `jsonb` instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's also a possible approach in MySQL, to have the JSON stored in a TEXT or JSON field... Even better than the currently accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
assets (

   id
   asset_type_id
   vendor_id
   cost
   purchase_date

)

asset_poperties (

    id
    asset_id
    asset_property_type_id
    value

)

asset_property_types (

     id
     property_type

)

asset_types (

   id
   asset_type

)

vendors (

   id
   vendor

)
```

Comment: This does not allow for variable fields

Comment: So the properties that do change go in the assets table and those that are common are stored in separate tables (asset_types, vendors, ...) and linked through foreign keys to the assets table.

Comment: But users can add asset types that will have different data attached to them, but I do not want users to be able to alter the structure of the database.

Comment: You can create an addition table like asset_properties with fields id, asset_property_type, value and then link that one to asset table.

Comment: I thought about that, but it would create very awkward queries.

Comment: Not really just one more JOIN, nothing else. Actually in a case like this, it might be better to query the list of additional properties separately.

Answer (score 4):

When I've been faced with this in the past, the "best" answer always ends up varying depending on how much processing I want to do in the database, vs how much in the client code.

For what it's worth, often the approach that has worked best for me in the past has been to end up with one table per optional attribute (in particular, not one table per entity type). So, in your examples above

```
assets (as per your example)
asset_types (as per you example)
division_assets (as per your example)
user_assets (as per your example)
colours
  asset_id, colour
weights
  asset_id, weight
serial_numbers
  asset_id, serial_number
```

Of course, depending on the trade-offs you need to make, this might be a bad choice for you. Personally, I like to keep the schema for data as explicit as possible, including data types and constraints, so I have no drama in changing the the tables next time a new attribute comes along.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another table for asset_metadata

```
asset_metadata
asset_metadata_id,asset_id,metadata_name,metadata_value
```

if you want to normalize and categorize the metadata, normalize it to this way:

```
asset_metadata
asset_metadata_id,asset_id,metadata_name_id,metadata_value

metadata_name
metadata_name_id,metadata_name_text
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend putting the common attributes like cost in conventional column.  Then add one more column in which you put a serialized collection of all the other variable asset attributes.

```
CREATE TABLE assets (
  asset_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cost NUMERIC(9,2),
  purchase_date DATE,
  variables TEXT
);
```

You can serialize the collection as JSON or XML or whatever you want.  Use whatever is most easily processed by your application code.

```
INSERT INTO assets VALUES (123, 49.95, CURDATE(), 'color: black; vendor: Acme Co.');
```

The advantage is that you can add new attributes to the text blob at any time.  The disadvantage is that you can't read or write an individual attribute, you have to treat the whole collection as a lump.

But you can index individual attributes to make them searchable.  You need to create a new table for each attribute you want to be searchable (but this could be a small subset of all attributes):

```
CREATE TABLE asset_color (
  asset_id INT NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (asset_id, color),
  KEY(color)
);
```

Not every asset is recorded in this table, only those assets that have a color.

Then you can do an indexed search for all assets that have a color attribute:

```
SELECT assets.*
FROM assets INNER JOIN asset_color USING (asset_id);
```

You can also do an indexed search limited to assets that have a color attribute, and the color is black:

```
SELECT assets.*
FROM assets INNER JOIN asset_color USING (asset_id)
WHERE color = 'black';
```

There is really no way to design a *normalized* database that permits variable attributes.  All normal forms require first that the table be a relation.  And a relation by definition must have a fixed set of attributes.

Other people are recommending an EAV table, but the "value" column in an EAV doesn't meet the definition of a relational column with a type (other consequences of this are that constraints don't work in an EAV table).  Therefore an EAV table isn't a relation, and cannot satisfy any normal form either.

Comment: Putting serialized attributes into a single column isn't normalized either: it violates the first normal form (atomic values). Solving this problem with a relational database with a *pure* normalized form won't be possible anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can create two new tables:

1) Defining multiple asset attributes in the following table (as many as the asset may have)

asset_id

asset_attribute

asset_value

2) asset_attribute table

attribute_id

asset_attribute

The logic would be that asset_attributes will need to be first defined in the asset_attribute table and then it can be used (linked/tagged) with any asset (as a foreign key, from a drop down list on UI) and a proper value entered.

Hope this helps.